# Javascript custom apply function

Tags: javascript, apply, referenceerror

I'm building a javascript library with a friend that's supposed to make HTML5 game creation easier (but it's really just for fun) and here's some code I'm having trouble with:

```
/* Calls f on all the elems of the list that pass p and implement f */
    var apply = function (f, p, list) {
        for (var i in list) {
            if (p(list[i]) === true && list[i][f] != undefined && typeof list[i][f] === 'function') {
                list[i][f]();
            }
        }
    };
    this.draw = function(p) {
        apply(moveView, p, this.views);
    };
```

The user would call the this.draw function and pass it a predicate. The function moveView that's being passed into the apply function would only be executed if every object in the views array implemented it.

However, my console is throwing an error saying "moveView is not defined" which makes sense because . At the point that I call my apply function, I don't want the interpreter to check if moveView exists or not, I just want to pass it in so I can check if each object that's being applied to, implements that function. I thought that maybe calling apply like `apply("draw", p, this.views);` would work but that didn't either because then in the apply function, f is not a function anymore, it's a string. I really just want to be able to pass any generic function name to my apply function so that I can then do all the checking inside there.

All my code can be found on my [Github](http://github.com/shadowthekid/GameBoard.js).

EDIT:

```
    /*View object*/
var View = (function(){
    var constr = function(f, o, i){
        this.frame = utility.checkFrame(f);
        this.orient = utility.checkOrientation(o);
        /*user identification string*/
        this.id = i;
        this.moveView = function(){
                console.log("testing");
        };
    };
return constr;
}());
```

Comment: Assuming `this.views` is a list of `View` objects, then `apply("moveView", p, this.views)` should work just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. It was in my View object:

```
var View = (function(){
this.moveView = function(){
            console.log("testing");
    };
var constr = function(f, o, i){
    this.frame = utility.checkFrame(f);
    this.orient = utility.checkOrientation(o);
    /*user identification string*/
    this.id = i;

};
return constr;
}());
```

I moved moveView outside the View object constructor and an error was no longer thrown. It was an issue of scope.

Comment: That the error is not thrown does not mean you solved the problem. Your "solution" assigns `moveView` to `window`, i.e. you make it a global variable/function. Of course this can be what you wanted, but it seems a bit odd to me.

Comment: Yeah I know, I ended up going with your answer about passing in a string. If you wanna put it as an answer, I'll gladly accept it.

Answer (score 0):

If your function does not exist when `apply()` is called it is also non-existent at the objects that your check your function against.

Also, if `f` is your function parameter, `list[i].f` is not evaluated to `list[i].yourFunction`. It will always be `list[i].f`. You need to check for `list[i][f]`.

Comment: Ok I'll fix that. But how do I pass in a generic function name without it checking to see if that function exists? I want the user to pass in a function name regardless of existence and all the checking will happen inside the apply function.

Comment: If you want your user to pass a function **name**, you are dealing with a string here. You simply cannot pass a variable that is not defined. It does not make sense anyhow.

Comment: Yeah that's what @Felix Kling said. And surprise! It works :D